# Where is MAP_FAILED returned

Tags: linux-kernel, mmap

A linux kernel newbie question.

the man pages of mmap state that `".. otherwise, it shall return a value of MAP_FAILED and set errno to indicate the error... "`

I have looked through the kernel code for mmap under /usr/src/linux/mm/mmap.c but I could not find a place where mmap returns MAP_FAILED.

Can anyone point me as to where can I find the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't find `MAP_FAILED` in the kernel; instead, it's defined in userspace and used by `mmap`, the userspace function that wraps the system call. See the [glibc source for `mmap`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/mmap64.c;h=b24b3f0c8bebabab28d578340442ebf15dd2bb2f;hb=00401ad5b08e86f2a912a640487c34006c7c27e3).

Comment: looks like the mmap returns MAP_FAILED, it looks like its mmap version of NULL.

Comment: @CallMeNorm Indeed it is, for reasons unknown to me. Note that `MAP_FAILED` is `(void *)(-1)`, which is never a valid page address if your pages are more than 1 byte large.